# Not able to add new project to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have less than 25 projects (well within the free limit). I have also deleted few unused projects. However, when trying to create a new project in Google Developer Console, I am getting a message "Increase Project Limit - You can create more projects after you request a project limit increase.".

Did the policy about 25 free projects on App Engine change? The document here "https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#create" still says 25 is the limit.

This is on my personal Google account and not on corporate account.

Answer (score 3):

When did you delete your projects? There is a 7-day waiting period before a project and associated data are permanently deleted. And also keep in mind the below details.

> Note that after the 7-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to
>   completely delete a project may vary. For example, if a project has
>   billing set up, it might not be completely deleted until the current
>   billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is
>   successfully charged. Additionally, the number and types of services
>   in use may also affect when the system permanently deletes a project.

You can check [Developer Console Help](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787) for more information. Furthermore, you can list all your projects pending deletion.

1. Go to the **Google Developers Console**.
2. From the projects list, select **Manage all projects**.
3. Below the list of projects, click **Projects pending deletion**.

Comment: When I deleted, I still had fewer than 25 projects. Would it be worth waiting for the projects to be actually deleted?

Comment: My understanding is that ([all your active projects] + [projects pending deletion] + [projects not yet deleted after the 7-day waiting period]) <= 25.

Comment: I have 12 projects but still, I can't create more